# Sidekiq - pick up DB changes made by another worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In a `Rails` app, I have `project`s which have many `task`s.
A `task` may have a `predecessor` that need to be completed before the task can start.

I use `sidekiq` for creating tasks.

```
class ScheduleProjectJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(project)
    tasks = Array(project.tasks)


    while !tasks.empty? do
      task = tasks.shift

      if task.without_predecessor? || task.predecessor_scheduled?
        ScheduleTaskJob.perform_later(task)
      else
        tasks << task
      end
    end
  end
```

I loop through the `task`s and schedule a task if it doesn't have a predecessor or, in case it has one, when the predecessor has been already scheduled.

To check if the predecessor has been scheduled, I check in the database if the predecessor state is `scheduled` (tasks are created with `created` state and updated to `scheduled` at the end of `ScheduleTaskJob`.

The check is as follows

```
Task.joins(:task_template).
     where(%q(task_templates.dep_id = :dep AND
              task_templates.tag = :tag AND
              tasks.state = :state),
              specification_id: task_template.dep_id,
              tag: task_template.runs_after_tag,
              state: 'scheduled').
     count > 0
```

The query above seems to work fine when I manually set the DB up and run it.
However, when it runs inside the `ScheduleProjectJob` the state of the predecessor task is always reported as `created` even if I can see in the DB the value in the record has been updated to `scheduled`.

Am I missing anything here?

end

Comment: How many "predecessors" one task has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord caches query results, when you're expecting query result to change, wrap your query with:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do # or YourModel.uncached do
  some_query.count
end
```